# Why don't decorators execute each time the decorated function is called?

Tags: python, decorator

I wrote the following code to learn closures and decorators in python.

The code executes fine in Pythonista on iPad.

But the decorator doesn’t work like I thought it would.  The decorator is intended to cause the function to print out with a unique random color with each call.  But it looks like the decorator is only called once for all calls to the function.  Can someone explain why ?

```
import random
import console 

def random_color(func): 
  r = random.random()
  g = random.random()
  b = random.random()
  print(f'console.set_color({r},{g},{b})')
  console.set_color(r,g,b)
  return func

@random_color  # run set_tag function through decorator function. 
def set_tag(tag):  
  def enclose_text(text):
    print( f'<{tag}>{text}</{tag}>')    
  return enclose_text 

# save enclose_text function with a remembered tag
h1 = set_tag('h1')
p  = set_tag('p')
br = set_tag('br')

# execute enclose_text with different text strings 
h1('Chapter One')
p('It was a dreary day. The rain had begun to set in ...')
br('')
h1('Chapter Two')
p('By the second day, the sun had returned to full strength.')
```

The output of all lines are the same color.  The next time I run it, all the lines have the same color - but a different color than from the first time it’s executed.  I expected the decorator to cause each tag to have a random color.

Can someone explain what this is not the case ?

Below is the output:

```
<h1>Chapter One</h1>
<p>It was a dreary day. The rain had begun to set in ...</p>
<br></br>
<h1>Chapter Two</h1>
<p>By the second day, the sun had returned to full strength.</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

The decorator executes when the function is *defined*; decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar for function application.

```
@random_color  # run set_tag function through decorator function. 
def set_tag(tag):  
  def enclose_text(text):
    print( f'<{tag}>{text}</{tag}>')    
  return enclose_text
```

is equivalent to

```
def set_tag(tag):  
  def enclose_text(text):
    print( f'<{tag}>{text}</{tag}>')    
  return enclose_text 

set_tag = random_color(set_tag)
```

You should define your decorator like this instead:

```
def random_color(func): 
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        r = random.random()
        g = random.random()
        b = random.random()
        print(f'console.set_color({r},{g},{b})')
        console.set_color(r,g,b)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper
```

That is, `random_color` should return a function which sets the console color, then calls the original function.

In addition, `set_tag` isn't the function you want to decorate: it's the function that `set_tag` creates:

```
def set_tag(tag):
    @random_color 
    def enclose_text(text):
        print( f'<{tag}>{text}</{tag}>')    
    return enclose_text
```

Before, `set_tag` was a function that would pick a random color, set the console to use that color, then return a function that would generate a tag. I assuming that the call to `set_color` affects the terminal at this point, not when `print` eventually gets called. Now, it's a function that returns a function that both picks a random color *and* generates a tag using that color.

Comment: The last line in `wrapper` should have `return`.

Comment: If I return the last line in wrapper, works no better than original code I had.  Every set_tag is colored exactly the same - as before.   (Although I do see the decorator changing color on every call - that color is not used as a free variable as I though it would be ).